# double polynomial division and product

Tags: polynomials

The polynomial $24x^{2}+14x+14a+4$ is multiplied by $2a−x$ and divided by $x−a$ to give a remainder of $\frac{−14}{3}$. What is the value of $a$?
I haven't really tried anything except subbing $a$ into the polynomial, which gives $24a^{2}+28a+4$.
from there I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: How do you translate the fact that the remainder is $-\frac{14}{3}$.

Comment: you tell me idk tbh

Comment: What does the result of subbing $a$ into the polynomial have to do with multiplying it by $2a-x$ or dividing it by $x-a$?  Are you familiar with polynomial long division?

Comment: can u write up an answer

Comment: $17=5.3+2$ so the remainder of the division of 17 by 3 is 2. It is the same for polynomials.

Answer (score 0):

Define $p(x)=(24x^{2}+14x+14a+4)(2a-x)$

When $p(x)$ is divided by $x-a$ the remainder is $\frac{-14}{3}$

So, by the remainder theorem $p(a)=\frac{-14}{3}$

This gives $(24a^{2}+14a+14a+4)(2a-a)=\frac{-14}{3}$

So we now have a cubic polynomial in $a$.

When rearranged to make the RHS zero we have $72a^{3}+84a^{2}+12a+14=0$

This can be factorized to $2(6a+7)(6a^{2}+1)=0$ and so there is one real solution for $a$, namely $a=\frac{-7}{6}$

Comment: OK thanks. I will edit later.